# SQL - How to select data row with Maximum value within a specific column? [Version 2]

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to create a new view with 2 different views using the following SQL:

```
SELECT a.[CourseID], a.[Course Code], a.[Course Title], a.[Result], a.[Employee No], 
   a.[Employee Name], a.[Section], max(b.ActStartDate) as [Last Training Date],
   b.ValidTo as [Validity Period],a.[Status], a.[Flag]
FROM [SQLDB3].[dbo].[Emp-OJT] as a 
INNER JOIN [SQLDB3].[dbo].[TrainingCourse_Record_Schedule] as b
   on a.[CourseID] = b.CourseID
GROUP BY a.[CourseID], a.[Course Code], a.[Course Title], a.[Result],a.[Employee No], a.[Employee Name], a.[Section], b.ValidTo,a.[Status], a.[Flag]
```

I'm aiming for a table result which gives me a single row of data for each unique [Course Code] & [Employee No] combo whose [Last Training Date] column contains the max value for that combination.

As its current state, the display shows an example of multiple data for some entries. Note that I removed some of the non-relevant columns:

```
CourseID | Course Code | Course Title | Employee No | Employee Name | Last Training Date | Validity Period | Status |   Flag
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6        | A001        | Admin        | 100002      | DUMM          |  2018-08-08        | NULL            | X      | Active
6        | A001        | Admin        | 100002      | DUMM          |  2019-02-07        | NULL            | X      | Active
```

I want it to show only the data with `[Last Training Date]` as `2019-02-07`. For the inner join statement, I even tried changing `a.[CourseID] = b.CourseID` to other sources like `[Employee No]`. But so far it still doesn't work.

What is the best method to fix this?

Comment: does not row_number help you in your earlier question?

Comment: it did solve it. But when I check the data content the `Last Training Date` showed me the wrong value. A data row that is supposed to be null ended up giving me an actual date. I thought if I save the 2 separate components as separate views then create a new view using them both, I could get a more accurate result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE APPLY

```
SELECT 
    a.[CourseID], a.[Course Code], a.[Course Title], a.[Result], a.[Employee No], 
    a.[Employee Name], a.[Section], b.ActStartDate AS [Last Training Date],
    b.ValidTo as [Validity Period],a.[Status], a.[Flag]
FROM
[SQLDB3].[dbo].[Emp-OJT] A
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 ActStartDate, ValidTo 
    FROM [SQLDB3].[dbo].[TrainingCourse_Record_Schedule] 
    WHERE CourseID = A.CourseID
    ORDER BY ActStartDate DESC
) B
```

For SQL Server 2000 use correlated subqueries

```
SELECT 
    a.[CourseID], a.[Course Code], a.[Course Title], a.[Result], a.[Employee No], 
    a.[Employee Name], a.[Section],
    a.[Status], a.[Flag], 
    (   SELECT TOP 1 ActStartDate 
        FROM [SQLDB3].[dbo].[TrainingCourse_Record_Schedule] 
        WHERE CourseID = A.CourseID
        ORDER BY ActStartDate DESC) AS [Last Training Date],
    (   SELECT TOP 1 ValidTo 
        FROM [SQLDB3].[dbo].[TrainingCourse_Record_Schedule] 
        WHERE CourseID = A.CourseID
        ORDER BY ActStartDate DESC) AS [Last Training Date],
FROM
[SQLDB3].[dbo].[Emp-OJT] A
```

Comment: Close. But it seems to change all the value  of `[Last Training Date]` for according to `Course Code` only. If I want to make it a combo of both `Course Code` and `Employee No`, how should I do it?

Comment: Also thanks for the tip to use Apply. Never knew this even existed.

Comment: Another thing to ask. If `ActStartDate` has a null value in it, will it be top priority when I `select top 1`? Because that is what I'm getting for some of my data rows.

Comment: Never mind. Ignore what I just asked. Everything seems to check out for now. Thanks. I'll mark this as correct.

Comment: Sorry... 1 more question, can this be saved as view?

Comment: Yes, you can do it

Comment: And another question... Does this view works in SQL Server 2000? My test server was SQL Server 2008 so I'm not sure if there is compatibility issues when I move it to my live server.

Comment: No, you will need subqueries to do that

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
SELECT a.[CourseID], a.[Course Code], a.[Course Title], a.[Result], a.[Employee No], 
   a.[Employee Name], a.[Section], max(b.ActStartDate) as [Last Training Date],
   b.ValidTo as [Validity Period],a.[Status], a.[Flag],row_number() over(partition by a.[CourseID],a.[Employee Name] order by b.ActStartDate desc) as rn
   FROM [SQLDB3].[dbo].[Emp-OJT] as a inner join [SQLDB3].[dbo].[TrainingCourse_Record_Schedule] as b
   on a.[CourseID] = b.CourseID
   group by a.[CourseID], a.[Course Code], a.[Course Title], a.[Result],a.[Employee No], a.[Employee Name], a.[Section], b.ValidTo,a.[Status], a.[Flag]
)A where rn=1
```